# Bootstrap 4.1 extra padding inside column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Having some trouble after transitioning to bootstrap 4.1. I had horizontal cards working fine in 4.0-alpha, but now, not so much. The following screenshot shows two attempts at aligning horizontal cards with about 75% card-text and 25% the image thumbnail on the right. The first attempt is a bare bones row with two columns and the second attempt was taken from an example [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/blog/#) (see card halfway down). I prefer simplicity for maintenance, but the second example obviously looks better (if you remove the border colors), but in either case I'm getting extra padding around the image and the 75:25 ratio is not stable depending on the image size. Would like the most responsive solution and maintainable solution if possible (i know... the cake eating beggar).

GOAL: Have equally sized horizontal cards aligned in a center column, with each card roughly 75% card-text and 25% image. I want to be able to adjust this ratio based on the size of the image I want or alternatively the size of the image div. So if I increase the image size/max-width it will increase the image column/flex-row/whatever, or increasing the image div will decrease the card-text div. But regardless of the native image size, it should fill the column with no padding.

*Also, both cards are in the same parent container, so I'm not sure why one is wider than the other.

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top:3%;">
        <div class="card" style="border:solid;border-color:black;">
          <div class="d-flex flex-row" >
            <div class="p-8 flex-grow-1" style="border:solid;border-color:green;">
              <h3>Card Title</h3>
              This text should expand to 75% of the parent container. Extra text. Extra text.
              Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text.
              Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text.
              Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text.
              Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text.
            </div>
            <div class="p-4 flex-grow-2" style="border:solid;border-color:red;">
              This should be 25%
              <img class="card-img-right flex-auto d-lg-block nopadding" src="https://hlfppt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png" style="width:70%;">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row" >
        <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250" style="border:solid;border-color:black;">
          <div class="col-lg-8" style="border:solid;border-color:green;">
            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
              <div class="card-text mb-auto">
                <h3>Card Title</h3>
                This text should expand to 75% of the parent container. Extra text. Extra text.
                Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text.
                Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text.
                Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text.
                Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4" style="border:solid;border-color:red;">
            This should be 25% with no padding
            <img class="card-img-right flex-auto d-lg-block nopadding" src="https://hlfppt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png" style="width:70%;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Looked at a number of solutions, but I'm not sure they apply since they are much older and 4.1 is so new.

**UPDATE 1**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row-fluid no-gutter">
        <div class="card" style="border:solid;border-color:black;">
          <div class="col-8" style="border:solid;border-color:green;">
            <h3>Card Title</h3>
            This text should expand to 75% of the parent container. Extra text. Extra text.
            Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text.
            Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text.
            Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text.
            Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text. Extra text.
          </div>
          <div class="col-4" style="border:solid;border-color:red;">
            This should be 25% with no padding
            <img src="https://hlfppt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png" style="width:70%;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250 m-3">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start flex-grow-1 pr-md-3">
          <h3>
            <a href="#">Some title</a>
          </h3>
          <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <img class="d-none d-md-flex" data-src="holder.js/200x200" alt="200x200" src="https://hlfppt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png"
             data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card flex-md-row box-shadow h-md-250 mx-3 mt-3">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-sm-8 d-flex  order-1 order-sm-0">
            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start pr-md-3">
              <h3>
                <a href="#">Some title</a>
              </h3>
              <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in.</p>
              <a href="#">Continue reading</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img class="d-block img-w-100" data-src="holder.js/200x200" alt="200x200" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1648332c5cf%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A10pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1648332c5cf%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2273.640625%22%20y%3D%22104.5%22%3E200x200%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
                 data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card flex-md-row box-shadow h-md-250 mx-3 mt-3">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-sm-8 d-flex  order-1 order-sm-0">
            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start pr-md-3">
              <h3>
                <a href="#">Some title</a>
              </h3>
              <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in.</p>
              <a href="#">Continue reading</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img class="d-block img-w-100" data-src="holder.js/200x200" alt="200x200" src="https://hlfppt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png"
                 data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250 m-3">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start flex-grow-1 pr-md-3">
          <h3>
            <a href="#">Some title</a>
          </h3>
          <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <img class="d-none d-md-flex" data-src="holder.js/200x200" alt="200x200" src="https://hlfppt.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png"
             data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Screenshot is at 25% browser zoom)

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

Current suggestion looks almost good but when the image is changed it doesn't adhere to the set width it seems. Or am I using data-src and src incorrectly?

Comment: You changed your question, and parts of my answer are now no longer relevant! Answers here are given to questions which are likely to help more than only OP. Changing the questions body is selfish and shows no respect to either answerer or future with same problem.

Comment: I don't understand how I changed my question. I only updated the code and screenshot based on what you suggested, mostly cut and paste. Question is still the same. I can clarify anything that isn't clear. Really appreciate your help and would like to give you the answer.

Comment: By updating your code with code from the answer you're changing the question and are asking a different question than the initial one. You shouldn't do that here. You're denying future visitors the help you already received.

Comment: OK. I wasn't sure if I should update the question or keep letting it get longer and longer. Sorry for the inconvenience. How can I fix it? If you replace your answer, I can put back in the question history.

Comment: If it gets too long, use the "Hide snippet" checkbox to allow snippets to be expandable. Most people prefix edits with "**Edit:**" to make it easy for everyone to understand the initial question and what the additional request/clarification is. Also, should you need to, use more than one snippet.

Comment: You forgot to use the CSS I added (which gives the image `width:100%`). That's why it doesn't work. The custom class `img-w-100` is not part of Bootstrap. I added it to style the image so it fills up the column. Alternatively, you could use `w-100` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note `p-*` classes are not similar to `col-*` classes. "**p**" here stands for "*padding*" and `p-4` cannot replace `col-4`.

If you want a 75/25 ratio, use `row no-gutters` on parent and `col-8` and `col-4` on the immediate children. If the image has a native width smaller than the column width, it is normal not to fill the column. To have it fill the column, give it

```
display:block;  /* or d-block class */
width: 100%;    /* or w-100 class */
height: auto;   /* or h-auto class */
```

Now the columns will keep the ratio and you can play with margin or padding classes starting from this.

Please note `col-*` should be ***direct children*** of `.row` or `.row-fluid`. The gutters system is smart and responsive, but relies on this markup.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="card flex-md-row box-shadow h-md-250 mx-3 mt-3">
    <div class="row w-100 no-gutters">
      <div class="col-sm-8 d-flex order-1 order-sm-0">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start pr-md-3">
          <h3>
            <a href="#">Some title</a>
          </h3>
          <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in.</p>
          <a href="#">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img class="d-block w-100 h-auto" data-src="holder.js/200x200" alt="200x200" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1648332c5cf%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A10pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1648332c5cf%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2273.640625%22%20y%3D%22104.5%22%3E200x200%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
          data-holder-rendered="true">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

If you want to use flexbox, *to allow the text to grow in the available space* - width minus image, which is what flexbox was created for in the first place, use this example:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250 m-3">
  <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start flex-grow-1 pr-md-3">
    <h3>
      <a href="#">Some title</a>
    </h3>
    <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#">Continue reading</a>
  </div>
  <img class="d-none d-md-flex" data-src="holder.js/200x200" alt="200x200" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1648332c5cf%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A10pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1648332c5cf%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2273.640625%22%20y%3D%22104.5%22%3E200x200%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
    data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
</div>
```

`m{*}-*-*` classes set `margin`, `p{*}-*-*` set `padding`, `h-*-*` set `height` and `d-*-*` set `display`.

To have two cards on same row, place them inside a row/col structure:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="card flex-md-row box-shadow h-md-250 mx-3 mt-3">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start flex-grow-1 pr-md-3">
          <h3>
            <a href="#">Some title</a>
          </h3>
          <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <img class="d-none d-md-block" data-src="holder.js/200x200" alt="200x200" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1648332c5cf%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A10pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1648332c5cf%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2273.640625%22%20y%3D%22104.5%22%3E200x200%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
          data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="card flex-md-row box-shadow h-md-250 mx-3 mt-3">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start flex-grow-1 pr-md-3">
          <h3>
            <a href="#">Some title</a>
          </h3>
          <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <img class="d-none d-md-block" data-src="holder.js/200x200" alt="200x200" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20200%20200%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1648332c5cf%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A10pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1648332c5cf%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2273.640625%22%20y%3D%22104.5%22%3E200x200%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"
          data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! See new screenshot in Question. The flexbox version is looking good, but I'm surprised I mucked up the easier col version. I know you said the col divs had to be a direct descendant, but I tried putting the card div above the row and that didn't help (didn't make sense either to have a row inside a card). Was hoping to use the col version if you can see what's wrong, since that will probably present less problems for me in the future (unless you think different).

Comment: @user, you said *"I want to be able to adjust this ratio based on the size of the image"*. That's what flexbox layout does. Anyway, I added a fixed ratio layout, as an example. Additionally, I added some CSS to make the image change size to fit full width of the column and also placed the image at the top when row wraps.

Comment: I did try adding the css to the local file under .img-w-100 { width: 100; } but that didn't work. Also tried adding display:block and height:auto, but got the same results. The class w-100 worked though, I'm guessing that is the bootstrap built-in class. Thanks for your help. I will mark this as answered.

Comment: If that case it's a specificity issue. `w-100` places `width: 100% !important` on the element.